# UL Height Inside of Form is 0px?

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome, safari

I'm having a particular issue that I was able to zero in on with a particular structure, and I'm not entirely sure why.

Here's the situation: designing a site that is served specifically to iPads, so I do most of my development in Windows Safari (other browsers don't matter). jQTouch generally creates pages of `<ul>`'s with `<li>` items for each, so my forms contain all of these.  The particular issue I am having is that when I have a `<ul>` block outside of a `<form>` tag, it displays correctly (as in, it stretches the `<ul>` to match whatever height it's contents takes). An easy way to visually check this is to see the background color of the `<ul>`.  However, whenever I put it into a `form` tag, the `<ul>` can no longer tell the height of its contents, and Safari assigns it `height: 0px` (in the first instance, its assigned a pixel amount that is calculated with its contents' heights, == correct)

Tried to pull out only the important HTML tags and CSS styling in the example - copied the composite CSS that Safari was applying to each tag in order to show precisely what my application is generating across all classes etc., and uses purposefully vague selectors for the example:

CSS:

```
div {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    background-color: #DADFE3;
    background-image: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(left, transparent, transparent 1px, #D4DADF 1px, #D4DADF 7px);
    bottom: auto;
    display: -webkit-box;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica;
    left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    right: auto;
    top: 0px;
    width: 1406px;
    z-index: 10;
}

form {
    -webkit-margin-after-collapse: separate;
    -webkit-margin-before-collapse: separate;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    bottom: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica;
    height: 671px;
    left: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    position: static;
    right: auto;
    top: auto;
    width: 1406px;
}

ul {
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.148438) 0px 1px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-margin-after-collapse: separate;
    -webkit-margin-before-collapse: separate;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    background-color: maroon;
    border-bottom-color: #CACFD6;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-left-color: #CACFD6;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-right-color: #CACFD6;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-top-color: #CACFD6;
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    bottom: auto;
    box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.148438) 0px 1px 0px 0px;
    color: gray;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: auto;
    line-height: normal;
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    position: static;
    right: auto;
    text-shadow: white 0px 1px 0px;
    top: auto;
    width: 1335px;
    clear: both;
}

li {
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            /* CSS above here */
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form action="/some/action" method="GET">
                <ul>
                    <li>Some items</li>
                    <li>Some items</li>
                    <li>Some items</li>
                    <li>Some items</li>
                    <li>Some items</li>
                    <li>Some items</li>
                </ul>
            </form>

            <ul>
                <li>Some items</li>
                <li>Some items</li>
                <li>Some items</li>
                <li>Some items</li>
                <li>Some items</li>
                <li>Some items</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can attempt to provide more information if needed - but putting together the above code in Safari (Win) will replicate the issue: UL inside of form has no height, UL outside does.

**Edit**: To quickly show what I'm seeing visually, I took a screenshot and pointed out what I'm seeing:
[image: Above issue in Safari on Windows 7 (Safari 5.1.2)]

**Edit**: Apparently this occurs the same way in Firefox. Was doing some heavy AJAX work and am more familiar with Firefox's Firebug extension for that purpose, so I checked what it looked like in Firefox and it occurs there, too. The UL has a height of 0 if its not explicitly set.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `overflow:auto;` to you list of rules for the `UL` tag, or remove the `float:left;` rule for your `LI` tag.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fs5Ju/)** of the `overflow:auto;` rule added.

Comment: You are correct, thanks for the answer. These did solve the issue, however due to how my layout is (for a variety of reasons) I ended up having to write some Javascript to set the height of the UL on the fly - so I'm constantly telling the UL what height it should be - none of these options will let the UL resize dynamically, so I have to do it myself in Javascript. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your root div is using `display: -webkit-box`, an implementation of the experimental Flexible Box model, but your form tag is set to `display: inline-block`. So the first UL is presented using one (new, experimental) model, while the form presents the UL in the traditional method.

Using typical display logic, floated children (your `li`s)  do not contribute to the height of their parents unless the floats have been "cleared." This is corrected (and expected) behavior, and j08691's method will clear those floats.

You apparently do not need to clear floats when using `-webkit-box`. But inside the `form` tag you are back in traditional box-model land and must do so.